# Objective-C Custom Class with Struct tutorial

Tags: objective-c, class, struct

I'm coming from AS3 to Obj-C, and classes are confusing me.  I want to create a ball class as a test, with colour, radius etc.  Looking through other people's code I've discovered they use structs to implement them, and this seems like a much nicer method.  I've searched but am unable to find a really clear explanation of what structs are, and how to implement them.

In terms of my ball class, to implement it I'd want to use something like `Ball *myBall = [Ball radius:(14), mass:(1)];` etc.  This seems like a nice clean way to do it.  Can anyone suggest some further reading on this?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Are you asking what a struct is, how you use one in a class or what? Because it sounds like you just want a class with two integer variables, but you keep mentioning structs.

Answer (score 2):

Read Apple's own [Objective-C Primer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/). It's worth reading. The documents linked there are also useful. You know, vendors (in this  case Apple) often have a nice set of documentations because they need to sell their technology...

For a comparison of ActionScript and Objective-C, see [this series of blog posts](http://andyj.be.s79833.gridserver.com/blog/?cat=11&paged=2) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Using classes straight of the bat would be a better idea as once you start developing you'll probably want to extend the functionality like object orientated methods (what classes are for).

Creating a class for ball with an appropriate constructor and properties would fit your needs.

I recommend starting [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html).